# Resolution of the constant sheaf $\mathbb C$.

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

The differential-graded algebra of complex-valued smooth differential operators $\mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet}$ on an $n$-dimensional complex manifold $X$ (real dimension $=2n$) is acyclic resolution of the constant sheaf $\mathbb C_{X^{2n}}$ of functions on the underlying real $2n$-dimensional manifold of $X$, i.e. we have a quasi isomorphsim

$\mathbb C_{X^{2n}}\rightarrow\mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet}$. (1)

At the same time, the de Rham complex of holomorphic differential operators $\Omega_X^{\bullet}$ on $X$ defines a resolution for the constant sheaf $\mathbb C_{X^{n}}$ of functions on the $n$-dimensional manifold $X$, i.e. we have a quasi-isomorphism

$\mathbb C_{X^{n}}\rightarrow\Omega_X^{\bullet}$. (2)

Both constant sheaves in $(1)$ and $(2)$ are defined on different spaces so they are not isomorphic. Here is the question I have:

The singular cohomology does not care if $X$ is smooth or holomorphic, it cares only about the topology on $X$. In other words we have $H_{\textrm{sing.}}^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb{C}_{X^{2n}})=H_{\textrm{sing.}}^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb{C}_{X^n})$. Since $X$ is paracompact and locally contractible, we also have $H_{\textrm{sing.}}^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb{C}_{X^{2n}})\cong H^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb C_{X^{2n}})\cong \mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(X, \mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet})$ where the second cohomology is the sheaf cohomology of $\mathbb {C}_{X^{2n}}$ and the last one denotes the hypercohomology of $\mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet}$. Similary, we have $H_{\textrm{sing.}}^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb{C}_{X^{n}})\cong H^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb C_{X^{n}})\cong \mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(X, \Omega_{X}^{\bullet})$. These implies the false conclusion $\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(X, \mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet})\cong\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(X, \Omega_X^{\bullet})$. That is imposiible and something must be wrong somewhere but I do not see where. Can someone provide some help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $H^{\bullet}(X, \mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet})$ and $H^{\bullet}(X, \Omega_{X}^{\bullet})$, exactly?  The cohomology of the chain complex of global sections of these sheaves?  Or something else?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reasonable comment. I mean the hypercohomology of both complexes of sheaves. I will indicate this in my question.

Comment: Why do you say that $\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(X, \mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet})\cong\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(X, \Omega_X^{\bullet})$ is false?

Comment: Because that would imply $H_{\textrm{de Rham}}^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb C)=\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(X, \Omega_X^{\bullet})$. But $\Omega_X^{\bullet}$ is not acyclic resolution of $\mathbb C_X$.

Comment: That's why you take hypercohomology, to get the "correct" answer even if your resolution is not acyclic.

Comment: But then $H_{\textrm{de Rham}}^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb C):=H^{\bullet}(\Gamma(X, \Omega_X^{\bullet}))=\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(X, \Omega_X^{\bullet})$. The last equality is not supposed to be valid for the holomorphic de Rham complex, no? That would mean that $\Omega_X^{\bullet}$ is acyclic which is not true, right?

Comment: That last equality is indeed invalid, but I don't see how you are concluding that it would be true.

Comment: Ok, if I follow, you say that the cohomology sheaves of $\mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet}$ and $\Omega_X^{\bullet}$ are not isomorphic, i.e. $\mathcal{H}^{\bullet}(\mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet})\neq\mathcal{H}^{\bullet}(\Omega_X^{\bullet})$, but the hypercohomologies are isomorphic.

Comment: What do you mean by "cohomology sheaves"?

Comment: Ok, maybe I start seeing my mistake. This chain of equalities is correct now: $H_{de Rham}^{\bullet}(X, \mathbb C)=H^{\bullet}(\Gamma(X, \mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet}))=\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(X, \Omega_X^{\bullet})$. I was implicitly defining the complex De Rham cohomology using $\Omega_X^{\bullet}$ in stead of $\mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet}$ which false, I  guess.

Comment: Right, complex de Rham cohomology is defined as the cohomology of complex-valued smooth differential forms, not of holomorphic differential forms. (At least, it is if you want "complex de Rham cohomology" to coincide with singular cohomology with complex coefficients.)

Comment: Cohomology sheaf means the cohomology of the complex of sheaves. Not to be confused with the hypercohomology of complex of sheaves which is the cohomology of global sections of a resolution of the complex of sheaves. A morphism of  complexes of sheaves is a quasi-isomorphism if it is an isomorphism between the cohomology sheaves of both complexes of sheaves.

Comment: The cohomology sheaves _are_ isomorphic: they're just the constant sheaf $\mathbb{C}$ in degree $0$, since both complexes are resolutions of that constant sheaf.

Comment: Interesting. If the cohomology sheaves are isomorphic that would mean that $H^{\bullet}(\Omega_X^{\bullet}(U))=H^{\bullet}(\mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet}(U))$ for any open set $U$ in $X$. In particualr when $U=X$. Is that really true? No counterexamples?

Comment: Why would it imply that?

Comment: Because I thought that the cohomology sheaf of a complex of sheaves $F^{\bullet}$ is defines as $\mathcal{H}^{\bullet}(F^{\bullet})(U):=\mathcal{H}^{\bullet}(F^{\bullet}(U))$. Is it wrong?

Comment: No; that definition will typically not even be a sheaf.  The definition is you just take kernel mod image in the abelian category of sheaves. (But note that the quotient in the category of sheaves is the *sheafification* of the naive quotient that is just defined pointwise.)

Comment: So my definition is wrong? Wait. How do I find kernel of a morphism of sheaves ? I thought you need to evaluate the complex of sheaves on small open $U$. This is another point of confusion which contributed to the falsehoods I wrote in my question.

Comment: To take the kernel of a morphism of sheaves, you can just take the kernel on each open set separately.  But to take the cokernel (and thus also to take the image, or a quotient of sheaves), you have to take the cokernel on each open set and then sheafify (the pointwise cokernel is typically only a presheaf, not a sheaf).

Comment: The sheafification of the quotient will alter the result substantially. Understood. So, the bottomline is that I have two quasi-isomorphisms $\mathbb  C_X\rightarrow\mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet}$ and $\mathbb  C_X\rightarrow\Omega_{X}^{\bullet}$ which imply two very important isomorphisms: 1) $\mathcal{H}^{\bullet}(\mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet})\cong\mathcal{H}^{\bullet}(\Omega_X^{\bullet})$ and $\mathbb  H^{\bullet}(X, \mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet})\cong\mathbb H^{\bullet}(X, \Omega_X^{\bullet})$. That is correct, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, Eric Wofsey. The discussion with you was very useful. I was able to fill some gaps in my understanding.

Comment: For what it's worth, this very issue is neatly highlighted on the first two pages of Matt Stevenson's note http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/algebraic_de_rham.pdf (which then goes on to review the algebraic version).

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong here: the conclusion that $\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(X, \mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet})\cong\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(X, \Omega_X^{\bullet})$ is correct.  This is in contrast with what you would get if you took cohomology of the chain complex of global sections instead of hypercohomology: in that case using $\mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet}$ would still give you singular cohomology (since the sheaves $\mathcal{A}_{X, \mathbb C}^{\bullet}$ are acyclic) but using $\Omega_X^{\bullet}$ would not in general.  In other words, to compute singular cohomology you can take the cohomology of the complex of global smooth complex-valued differential forms (this is essentially just the classical de Rham theorem), whereas if you use holomorphic differential forms you instead need to take hypercohomology of the complex of sheaves instead of just cohomology of global sections (and this is a different and somewhat harder result than the classical de Rham theorem).

Comment: Great answer. Thanks